# Value no elemento input não é exibido - (embora valor, esteja sendo carregado corretamente ) - Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Olá!

Estou retornando um objeto através do ajax e atribuindo os valores aos respectivos campos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando como exemplo o campo título:

```
$('#txt_titulo').val(objeto_menu.titulo);
```

Porem, observei uma coisa, quando abri o console do navegador.

```
<input type="text" id="txt_titulo" class="form-control input-sm titulo lower valid" name="titulo" tabindex="4" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Título">
```

Embora o campo esteja corretamente preenchido com o valor vindo do servidor, eu não encontrei no elemento o `value="Menu".`

Logo, deveria encontrar algo do tipo:

```
<input type="text" id="txt_titulo" class="form-control input-sm titulo lower valid" name="titulo" tabindex="4" autocomplete="off" value="Menu">
```

Estou alterando algumas coisas no front-end, e estou tendo um certo problema porque preciso deste `value`.

Alguém sabe porque não é exibido ?

Comment: Está correto, ele não é exibido mesmo no console. A menos que você tenha definido o atributo value no seu input. E você também não precisa se preocupar dele aparecer ou não pq todo input tem um atributo value e ele está la msm q vc n esteja vendo ele no console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas completando o meu comentário.

Se você quiser ver esse atributo no Console (Isso não é necessário).

**Você pode fazer isso:**

```
$('#txt_titulo').attr('value', objeto_menu.titulo);
```

Mas o mais comum é utilizar da forma que você fez mesmo e não se preocupar dele não estar visível no console.

**Porque você pode consultar o valor dele desta forma:**

```
$('#txt_titulo').val();
```